# How to append elements to multiple arrays on the same line?

Tags: arrays, powershell, element

I know it is possible to set mulitple variables to the same value on the same line :

```
$a, $b = "value"
```

My question is, Is it possible to do the same thing with Arrays and "+=" operators ?

I've tried this :

```
 $a = @()
 $b = @()
 $a, $b += "test"
```

But i get the following error :

```
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ $a, $b += test
+ ~~~~~~
L'expression d'affectation n'est pas valide. Vous devez placer un élément affectable, comme une variable ou une propriété, à gauche d'un opérateur
d'affectation.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidLeftHandSide
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it in the same line:

```
$a,$b | foreach {$_ += 'test'}
```

Edit: that actually doesn't work.  This does

```
$a,$b = $a,$b |% {,($_ += 'test')}
```

Not sure if that's any better than the iex or not.......

Comment: Thanks ! Are you able to echo the array elements after that ? When I try to get the value of $a or $b nothing is returned.

Comment: @xashcorex try "a","b" | foreach { iex "`$$_ += 'test'"} but I really don't like it ;)

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that the values of $a and $b are in the pipeline, not the variables themselves.

Comment: @CB - You're right, that doesn't really work. Seems like it should, tho.

Comment: @CB It looks a bit "heavy" but it works haha ;) thanks for your help !

Comment: @mjolinor hum.. your second one return always [string] and  never [object[]]. Maybe just on my box, can you verify? thanks

Comment: TANJ!  Updated again.